# A variation of the infinite monkey theorem

Tags: probability-theory

There are many variations of this problem. In particular one could have a certain number of monkeys and even a certain number of keys. I want to prove a specific case. Suppose I had one monkey, and suppose there were two keys only. I guess for the fun of it, we could translate Shakespeare into binary and our two keys could be zero and one. Then what would be the proof of this specific infinite monkey theorem?

Here is what I tried.

The probability of hitting one of the keys is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$. So if I hit the keys $k$ times, I would have a $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^k}$ chance of getting what I desired. Now from here I was trying to do some trick like $1 - (1 - \frac{1}{2^k})$ and then try to introduce $e$ into this but I am getting a little confused.

The help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem here is that you need to be willing to look at substrings. The probability of actually getting the full string to be a particular specified string is extremely small, but the probability of a particular substring appearing in an arbitrarily long string converges to $1$ as the length of the string grows.

Answer (score 0):

Given any event with low but non-zero probability, if you repeat the trial infinitely often then you get the event with probability $1$. Indeed, it is probability $1$ that the event will occur infinitely often.

So if Shakespeare is $n$ bits, then the probability is $1/2^n$ that the monkey will type Shakespeare in the first $n$ bits. Same for bits $n+1$ to $2n$, and bits $mk+1$ to $(m+1)k$. So the probability that the monkey will type Shakespeare in some block of bits of that form eventually is $1$.

The monkey might also type Shakespeare in bits $2$ to $n+1$, but that is in addition.